gcp synthesizeLongAudio returns Rejected by impersonation_policy error
I'm trying to use google's synthesizeLongAudio API, following google's quickstart page
I am sending an initial request to https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT}/locations/global:synthesizeLongAudio?key=${process.env.API_KEY}
Then I'm polling on the returned operation, until I get a done: true status.
However, this status returns with the following error:

{
name: 'projects/***/locations/global/operations/***', 
done: true,
error: {
   code: 16,
   message: 'Invalid authentication from policy (go/gcs-rpc-sp): Rejected by impersonation_policy (attempt to impersonate cloud-ml-tts-frontend@prod.google.com -- if impersonation was unintentional, see go/dpci-faq#from-context-impersonation): Permission 'auth.impersonation.impersonateProdUser' not granted to cloud-tts-lrs-worker-composite@prod.google.com, because no ALLOW or ALLOW_WITH_LOG rule includes that permission.; '

  }
}

What could be causing this issue?

I fixed this by replacing the API_KEY with proper credentials from a gcs service account.
Using the node.js client, my call now looks like this:

import { v1beta1 } from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech';

const credentials = {
  client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL!,
  private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY!
};


const ttsLongClient = new v1beta1.TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient({
  credentials
});

...
const response = await ttsLongClient.synthesizeLongAudio(request);

And it returns the proper response and saved the file to the bucket.
